# Extending an activity with BaseActivity executing code oncreate?

Tags: java, android

I have many activities in which I need to execute some code on create, this code has to do with display preferences such as different themes, hiding the status bar etc.

This is an example of one of the activites:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }
}
```

Base activity in turn has this code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

        // getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // System.out.println("BaseActivity");

}
```

I'm trying to run some code on create but I cannot manage to do it. How can I run the code from above as soon as possible using BaseActivity?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. you are overriding onCreate in MainActivity, but show code for onCreateOptionsMenu in BaceActivity.  User2381750 has the correct answer to call the BaseActivity onCreate method from MainActivity.  Remember that super calls must be the first code in a method (you can not declare variables above the super call).

Comment: I corrected the question. It was just to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I just used oncreate because thought it would be a good way of running my two lines of code as soon as possible.

Comment: the onCreateOptionsMenu is not the place to call code as soon as possible, you should focus on the Activity lifecycle or the fragment lifecycle for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call super.onCreate(Bundle bundle) in the childs onCreate method to call the onCreate of the parent.

This is a common practice to abstract code from an Activity for reuse in other activities.

e.g.:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Log.v(TAG,"MainActivity");
    }
}



public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Log.v(TAG,"BaseActivity");
    }
}
```

I personnaly do this a lot but I often prefer the following for having better maintainable code:

> composition over inheritance

Comment: thanks! I started with java a month ago. This will help me a lot